# SQL Queries Count with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Queries for the first time and learning it.
I've got a table like this:

| yearName | productcompanyID |
| --- | --- |
| 2001 | ID 1 |
| 2001 | ID 1 |
| 2001 | ID 2 |
| 2001 | ID 1 |
| 2001 | ID 1 |
| 2002 | ID 1 |
| 2002 | ID 1 |
| 2002 | ID 2 |
| 2002 | ID 2 |
| 2003 | ID 2 |

And I would like to count how many times a productcompanyID appear but counting it only once for a year. (Sorry my English is not my language and I might not be clear)

What I mean, for the moment I've writtent this SQL:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(productcompanyid),
    COUNT(productcompanyid)
  FROM mydatabase
  GROUP BY productcompanyid
```

And it gives me the result as ID 1: 6 and ID 2 : 4.

What I would like to have is ID 1 : 2 (as it appears at least once in year 2001 and year 2002) and ID 2: 3 (as it appears at least once in year 2001, year 2002 and year 2003)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to count the number of distinct *years* that appear for each `productcompanyid`, but you're asking for a count of `productcompanyid`, not a count of distinct years.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. `SELECT DISTINCT(productcompanyid), COUNT(productcompanyid)` is simply `SELECT DISTINCT productcompanyid, COUNT(productcompanyid)`, and as you group by `productcompanyid`, the resulting rows are already distinct, so what you have is `SELECT productcompanyid, COUNT(productcompanyid)`. And as a `productcompanyid` is never null, this is the same as `SELECT productcompanyid, COUNT(*)`. But you don't want to count all rows per `productcompanyid`, but distinct years, i.e. `SELECT productcompanyid, COUNT(DISTINCT yearName)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to combine count and distinct, something like this:

```
select productcompanyID, count(distinct yearName) as distinctYears
from mydatabase
group by productcompanyID
```

Comment: Thanks that was it, don't know why I didn't think about that

Answer (score 0):

The simplest query and have some additional performance are using 2 level aggregation, eg:

```
--create temp table named #table1 and add row1

select 2001 yearName,   'ID 1' productcompanyID into #table1


--add remaining rows to #table1

insert into #table1

select 2001,    'ID 1' union all

select 2001,    'ID 2' union all

select 2001,    'ID 1' union all

select 2001,    'ID 1' union all

select 2002,    'ID 1' union all

select 2002,    'ID 1' union all

select 2002,    'ID 2' union all

select 2002,    'ID 2' union all

select 2003,    'ID 2' 


--/query to count how many times a productcompanyID appear each a year*/


select productcompanyID, count(1) cnt

from (

    select yearName, productcompanyID

    from #table1 

    group by yearName, productcompanyID

)a

group by productcompanyID
```

It should give the result as what you asking on the question.

[image: the result as on question]